# Composing Haskell tree structures

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

I got a problem with thinking recursively in Haskell.

I am trying to build a survey application where questions conditionally lead to new questions based on the user's answers.

I got:
- `Questions` - a list of questions
- `QuestionPaths` - a list of question paths of questions which lead to new questions
- `Answers` a list of user's answers

You can think of `QuestionPaths` as a list of tuples where:

```hs
type QuestionPath = (QuestionId, AnswerChoice, NextQuestionId)
```

Basically this would read: *If user answers a question* `QuestionId` *with an answer* `AnswerChoice`, *ask him* `NextQuestionId` *next.*

I have attempted to model this problem domain with [multiway trees](http://%20I%20got%20problem%20with%20thinking%20recursively%20in%20Haskell.%20%20I'm%20trying%20to%20build%20a%20survey%20application%20where%20questions%20conditionally%20lead%20to%20new%20questions%20based%20the%20user's%20on%20answers.%20%20I%20got:%20-%20%60Questions%60%20-%20a%20list%20of%20questions%20%20%20%20%60QuestionPaths%60%20-%20a%20list%20of%20question%20paths%20which%20lead%20to%20new%20questions%20%20-%20%60Answers%60%20a%20list%20of%20user's%20answers%20%20You%20can%20think%20of%20%60QuestionPaths%60%20as%20a%20list%20of%20tuples%20where:%20%60%60%60haskell%20(QuestionId,%20AnswerChoice,%20NextQuestionId)%20%60%60%60.%20Basically%20this%20would%20read:%20_If%20user%20answers%20a%20question_%20%60QuestionId%60%20_with%20an%20answer_%20%60AnswerChoice%60,%20_ask%20him_%20%60NextQuestionId%60%20_next._%20%20I've%20attempted%20to%20model%20this%20problem%20domain%20with%20multiway%20trees%20(nodes%20can%20have%20multiple%20children):%20%60%60%60haskell%20data%20YesNo%20=%20Yes%20%7C%20No%20data%20AnswerChoice%20=%20%20%20Skip%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20Boolean%20YesNo%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20ChooseOne%20[Text]%20%20type%20Condition%20=%20AnswerChoice%20%20data%20QuestionTree%20=%20QuestionNode%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20question%20%20%20%20%20%20::%20Question%20%20%20%20%20,%20userAnswer%20%20%20%20::%20Maybe%20AnswerChoice%20%20%20%20%20,%20children%20%20%20%20%20%20::%20QuestionForest%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20type%20QuestionForest%20=%20[QuestionTree]%20%60%60%60%20Unfortunately,%20I'm%20clueless%20now%20on%20how%20to%20write%20algorithms%20that%20compose%20trees%20like%20this.%20%20%20I%20basically%20need%20these%20kinds%20of%20functions%20for%20composition%20and%20traversal:%20%60%60%60haskell%20--%20Constructs%20the%20tree%20from%20seed%20data%20constructTree%20::%20Questions%20-%3E%20QuestionPaths%20-%3E%20Answers%20-%3E%20QuestionTree%20%20--%20%7C%20Inserts%20answer%20to%20question%20in%20the%20tree%20answerQuestion%20::%20Question%20-%3E%20AnswerChoice%20%20--%20%7C%20Fetches%20the%20next%20unanswered%20question%20by%20traversing%20the%20tree.%20getNextUnanswered%20::%20QuestionTree%20-%3E%20Question%20%60%60%60%20%20**Can%20you%20please%20help%20me%20understand%20what%20would%20be%20the%20best%20ways%20to%20construct%20and%20traverse%20a%20tree%20such%20as%20this?**) (nodes can have multiple children):

```hs
data YesNo = Yes | No
data AnswerChoice =   Skip
                    | Boolean YesNo
                    | ChooseOne [Text]

type Condition = AnswerChoice

data QuestionTree = QuestionNode {
      question      :: Question
    , condition     :: Condition
    , userAnswer    :: Maybe AnswerChoice
    , children      :: QuestionForest
    }

type QuestionForest = [QuestionTree]
```

Unfortunately, I am clueless now on how to write algorithms that compose trees like this.

I basically need these kinds of functions for composition and traversal:

```hs
-- Constructs the tree from seed data
constructTree :: Questions -> QuestionPaths -> Answers -> QuestionTree

-- | Inserts answer to question in the tree
answerQuestion :: Question -> AnswerChoice

-- | Fetches the next unanswered question by traversing the tree.
getNextUnanswered :: QuestionTree -> Question
```

**Can you please help me understand what would be the best way to construct and traverse a tree such as this?**

Comment: A map might be more appropriate: `type QuestionTree = Data.Map.Map (QuestionID, AnswerChoice) QuestionID`.

Comment: Or `Map QuestionID (Map AnswerChoice QuestionID)` for the "curried" version.

Comment: @chepner How would that replace the tree? I mean that the tree is the structure to build so that a user could be asked a series of conditional questions in a sequence. Like "Did you go to the gym?" Yes -> "How long did you work out at the gym for?"

Comment: @Hopia  try it and see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'd do in such a case, is to store the answers in a separate data structure - *not* to insert them in the questions tree; put the answers in a separate list/Set, or in a file or database, and let the questions tree be immutable.

In order to keep track of which questions remain to be asked, you can "consume" the tree - keep your program state pointing to the next question, throwing away the questions already answered (letting the garbage collector reclaim them).

I'd design the tree like this:

```hs
data AllowedAnswers = YesOrNo {
                        ifUserAnsweredYes :: QuestionTree,
                        ifUserAnsweredNo :: QuestionTree
                      }
                      | Choices [(Text, QuestionTree)]

data QuestionTree = Question {
      description :: Text
    , allowedAnswers :: AllowedAnswers
    , ifUserSkipsThisQuestion :: QuestionTree
  }
  | EndOfQuestions
```

Notice several things:

- You don't have to worry about multiple possible paths leading to the same question - you can place the same QuestionTree node in multiple places, and it will be shared (Haskell won't create multiple copies of it)
- This design has no place to hold the user's answers - they are stored elsewhere (i.e. a list somewhere, or a file) - no need to mutate the question tree.
- As the user answers questions, just move your "pointer" to the next QuestionTree, depending on what the user answered.

As for "how to construct this tree from the (QuestionId, AnswerChoice, NextQuestionId) list" - I think I'd first convert it into a map: ```Map QuestionId    [(AnswerChoice, Maybe QuestionId)], then I'd construct the tree by, starting with the ID of the first question, and fetching its immediate children from the Map, build the subtrees.

Example (for a *very* simplified case where the only possible answers are "yes" or "no", with no skipping allowed):

```hs
buildTree questionMap questionId = case Map.lookup questionId questionMap of
  Nothing -> EndOfQuestions
  Just (description, [("yes", nextQuestionIdIfYes), ("no", nextQuestionIdIfNo)]) ->
    Question { description = description
               , allowedAnswers = YesOrNo {
                   ifUserAnsweredYes = buildTree questionMap nextQuestionIdIfYes
                   , ifUserAnsweredNo = buildTree questionMap nextQuestionIdIfNo
                 }
               , ifUserSkipsThisQuestion = EndOfQuestions
             }
```

If you are wondering "why not just use the Map directly?" - yes, you could (and often it will be the right solution), but consider:

- The QuestionTree structure expresses the programmer's intention more idiomatically than a Map of Id -> Thing
- It is structurally guaranteed to have a child QuestionTree whenever pertinent - no need to do Map.lookup, which will return a Maybe, which you must verify that contains a Just (even when you *know* there is going to be a next question, even if it is EndOfQuestions)

Comment: +1 for a good approach.  Note that, even though the *data structure* allows question node sharing, the way this `buildTree` implementation works, question nodes for duplicate questions *won't* be shared, but that's probably not worth "fixing", unless you are processing a large number of completed questionnaires over the same, persistent tree and performance becomes an issue.

Comment: @k-a-buhr Yes, the ideal way to ensure sharing would be to 1) find the leaf nodes and 2), then build the tree from the bottom up, but that would be too complex to fit in an answer (specially since the OP is still wrapping their head around recursion)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution design with practical examples! I'm experimenting with it right now. I'm actually generating the possible answer choices and mapping their consequential successor questions straight from the database dynamically. Moreover, a single answer to a question may result in multiple (sibling) successor questions. So it complicates the control flow somewhat

Comment: Since you solve my inherent recursion issue with tree building with this solution I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help!